# google geocharts make regions clickable

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I made this geochart from google for my website, but I want the regions to be clickable. So when I click on it to show me information, I want to add about that region. I want to style the output text.

Also another thing: I want to display only the map of the country without the countries around so I want the map shape to be as the country (in this case Macedonia) and not as a rectangle. Below is the js code:

```
 <html>
      <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'city');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});var ivalue = new Array(); var name = new Array();

    data.addRows([[{v:'MK-76',f:'Tetovë'},0,'Kipper Market']]);
    ivalue['MK-TE'] = 'Obama (D)  will <span style="color:#444; font-weight:bold;">win</span> in Alaska.';


    data.addRows([[{v:'MK-19',f:'Gostivar'},0,'Kipper Market']]);
    ivalue['MK-GV'] = 'Obama (D)  will <span style="color:#444; font-weight:bold;">win</span> in Alaska.';

    data.addRows([[{v:'MK-40',f:'Kërçovë'},0,'Kipper Market']]);
    ivalue['MK-KI'] = 'Obama (D)  will <span style="color:#444; font-weight:bold;">win</span> in Alaska.';





     var options = {
     backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },
     colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 49,  colors: ['#ec2227','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#438094','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#DE3403','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E','#E0D39E',]},
     legend: 'none',  
     backgroundColor: {fill:'none',stroke:'none' ,strokeWidth:0 },  
     datalessRegionColor: '#f5f5f5',
     displayMode: 'regions', 
     enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
     resolution: 'provinces',
     sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
     region:'MK',
     keepAspectRatio: true,
     width:100 + "%",
     height:100 + '%',
     tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus'}  
     };
      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization')); 
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
      var selection = chart.getSelection();
      if (selection.length == 1) {
      var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
      var selectedRegion = data.getValue(selectedRow, 0);
      if(ivalue[selectedRegion] != '') {document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = ivalue[selectedRegion];}
      if(name[selectedRegion] != '') {document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name[selectedRegion];}
      }
      });
      chart.draw(data, options);



      go();

      window.addEventListener('resize', go);

      function go(){
       chart.draw(data, options);
       }
      }

      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">
      <div id="visualization"></div>
      <div id="message"></div>
     </div>

      </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
    if (selectedItem) {
      var country = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
      alert (country);

      if(ivalue[country] != '') {document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = ivalue[country];}
      if(name[country] != '') {document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name[country];}
    }    
  });
```

Comment: this is a really interesting solution. i wanted to vote up ur answer but i need 15 reputation for that...but... i need the information to be displayed below the map as normal text (which will be good if u show me how to style it as well. some of the text to appear bold and some only as paragraph). also what about getting rid of the countries around. how can i edit this svg to delete the path od the countries around? i can see it when in inspect element on chrome but i dont know where to edit it.